# I'm furious with his CONSTANT(LY) laughing at the girl - CONSTANT or CONSTANTLY?

Tags: modifiers

### Which one, adverb or adjective, modifies the gerund after its possessive?

This is an example to make the above question clear: `I'm furious with HIS CONSTANT(LY) laughing at the girl`.

Which modifier, CONSTANT or CONSTANTLY, do you think is correct?

Comment: This is relevant, although it may not be simple enough: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134352/should-i-modify-a-gerund-using-an-adjective-or-an-adverb

Comment: Yeah I read that before, but whatabout a Ving right behind its possessive? Is it treated as a verb or a noun?

Comment: I'd use constant, it should be a noun string modified by an adj